# method.toString() exclude/include 'use strict'

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, tostring

method.toString() add 'use strict' in Firefox, not in IE or Chrome.

Javascript code:

```
'use strict';
var myMethod = function foo(){return 1};
result = myMethod.toString();
console.log(result);
```

[Plunker to reproduce it](http://plnkr.co/edit/xI9khl?p=info)

Results:

- Chrome 39.0: "function foo(){return 1}"
- Internet 11: "function foo(){return 1}"
- Firefox 33.1: "function foo(){ "use strict"; return 1}"

Is it possible to define somehow that the directive 'use strict' should be include/exclude in toString()?

Comment: I guess its not possible. If you define, `'use strict'` before any method, then all its prototype will flow strict mode.  However, it is possible to define strict mode for a particular method, instead of whole js file.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this to determine strict mode and 'insert' it into the `toString` result:

```
var strictMode = (function() { return !this; })() ? '"use strict"; ' : '';
var result = myMethod.toString()
                 .replace(/"use strict";/, '') // FF prevent doubling
                 .replace(/{/, '{'+strictMode);
```

See updated [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYdvOgeVto53L86N8wUi?p=preview) or check the code snippet

```js
'use strict';

var strictMode = (function() { return !this; }()) ? '"use strict"; ' : '';
var myMethod = function foo(){return 1};

$(function(){
  $("#function").append(
      myMethod.toString()
       .replace(/"use strict";/, '') // to prevent a double 'use strict' in firefox
       .replace(/{/, '{'+strictMode) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello stackOverflow!</h1>
<h2>My Function to String</h2>
<p id="function"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
'use strict';
 var myMethod = function foo(){return 1};
var result = myMethod.toString().replace('\n"use strict";\n','');// exclude the use strict
 console.log(result);
```